# Horizontally centering a div in a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

I have 3 flex items (each item is a div).  Each flex item contains an image, 2 paragraph tags, and a div (For a button).  I am trying to horizontally center each button in each flex item.

I have tried setting `justify-content:center;` in the flex container but this did not work.  (I don't think this is what I want anyway because I only want the div to be horizontally centered) I also tried setting `margin: 0 auto;` to the button.  Neither of these seem to work.  Currently, each flex item has a width of 33%, so I set the inner div to have `position: absolute;` and `left: 16.5%;` (Half of the containers width).  But this doesn't look right.  This is the closest I got.  Any ideas on how to make this look better?

HTML:

```
<section class="overview-section">
  <h2>Overview</h2>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550129460-d47c2040f9df?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=282&q=80">
      <p class="under-text">TITLE GOES HERE</p>
      <p class="txt">adsf adsf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf </p>
      <div class="btn">Learn more</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550129460-d47c2040f9df?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=282&q=80">
      <p class="under-text">TITLE GOES HERE</p>
      <p class="txt">adsf adsf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
      </p>
      <div class="btn">Learn More</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550129460-d47c2040f9df?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=282&q=80">
      <p class="under-text">TITLE GOES HERE</p>
      <p class="txt">adsf adsf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
      </p>
      <div class="btn">Learn more</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,500");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches");

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -50px;
}

.box {
  position: relative; /* button will be positioned relative to this container */
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 33%;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.under-text {
  font-family: "Staatliches", cursive;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.txt {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.5%;
  bottom: 0;

  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rPqgVm

Expected result: Each div in the flex items should be horizontally centered.

Comment: Your `btn` is not a flex item (flex child), your `box` is, so if you make the `box` display flex, with flex direction column, and then set `align-items: center` they will. And remove absolute position on `btn`. Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYJLKy?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also wrap the btn div in another div and add

```
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
```

and remove absolute and left from existing btn div.

modified codePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErOYPw

Comment: Thank you.  I kept ```position: absolute``` so that I can set ```bottom: 0``` and get the button to the bottom margin of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Remove from

```
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 16.5%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And add in

```
.box {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about `.btn` correct? If so you have two options.

Remove the absolute position and give it auto margins. ("auto" means as much as you can get equally)

```
.btn {
 // margin top & bottom - margin left& right
 margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Or if you keep the absolute position you need to set the left to 50% and then pull the left corner of the div BACK 50% of it's width

```
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Grid but maybe this suggestion will help.  Put the button  in a container of it's own and then center it within that container.

```
<div class = 'btncontainer'>
    <div class="btn">Learn more</div>
</div>
```